# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac{2x}{e}}{\ln(1+(-\frac{2x}{e}))}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I know that: $$\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}=1$$

But why $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac{2x}{e}}{\ln(1+(-\frac{2x}{e}))}$$ is 1 too?

---

$$\lim_{x\to 0} 1 : \frac{\ln(1+(-\frac{2x}{e}))}{-\frac{2x}{e}}=1:\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{\ln(1+(-\frac{2x}{e}))}{-\frac{2x}{e}}=1:1=1$$

It's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=-2x/e$.  Then, as $x\to 0$, $y\to 0$.

Next, we see that

$$\frac{(-2x/e)}{\log(1+(-2x/e))}=\frac{y}{\log(1+y)}=\frac{1}{\frac{\log(1+y)}{y}}$$

Hence, we can assert that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(-2x/e)}{\log(1+(-2x/e))}=\frac{1}{\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\log(1+y)}{y}}=1$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. We have
$$
x \to 0 \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{2x}{e} \to 0.
$$

Comment: If $x \to 0 \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{2x}{e} \to 0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac{2x}{e}}{\ln(1+(-\frac{2x}{e}))}=\frac{0}{\ln(1+0)}$?

Comment: If $\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}=1$, then in particular with $a:=-\frac{2x}e$ we get $\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{\ln(1+(-\frac{2x}{e}))}{-\frac{2x}{e}}=1.$ Are you Ok with this?

Comment: Yes. But why $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac{2x}{e}}{\ln(1+(-\frac{2x}{e}))}=1$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The function $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)$ as long as the sequence does not tend to zero.