# Why $\lim\limits_{a\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

In [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072654/limit-lim-x-to-0-frac-frac2xe-ln1-frac2xe), to me wrote, that $\lim\limits_{a\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}=1$, but why?

$\lim\limits_{a\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}=\lim\limits_{a\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+0)}{0}=|\frac{0}{0}|$ or am I wrong?

Comment: if d'hospital is not allowed use taylor expansion.

Comment: I can't use  L'Hôpital's rule and Taylor series.

Comment: @divisor  When $a \to 0$, $\textrm{ln}(1+a) \sim a$.

Comment: Yes, but it is: $\frac{0}{0}$ ?

Comment: plug in the taylor expansion and cancel out $a$.

Comment: @Max without Taylor expansion.

Comment: What definition do you use for the logarithm function?

Comment: http://images.slideplayer.com/10/2810060/slides/slide_20.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $\ln$ is a continuous function.

Thus, $\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}=\ln\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow0}(1+a)^{\frac{1}{a}}=\ln{e}=1$

Comment: $\ln\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow0^+}(1+a)^{\frac{1}{a}}$; $(1+a)^{\frac{1}{a}}=1^{\frac{1}{0}}$?

Comment: @divisor $\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow0^+}(1+a)^{\frac{1}{a}}=e$. It follows from $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$.

Comment: Michael Rozenberg, why is that?

Comment: And why $a\rightarrow0^+$, not $a\rightarrow0$?

Comment: @divisor Take a calculator and calculate $\left(1+\frac{1}{1000000}\right)^{1000000}$.

Comment: @divisor $a\rightarrow0^+$ was typo. Thank you!

Comment: I understand $(1+\frac{1}{1000000}$, but $z^{1000000}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51399/discussion-between-divisor-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you must know by now derivatives, so:

$$f(a):=\log(1+a)\implies f'(0):=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{f(0+a)-f(0)}a=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{\log(1+a)}a$$

and now just substitute:

$$f'(0)=\left.\frac1{1+a}\right|_{a=0}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}nx^n$$

Comment: $\lim_{a\to 0} \ln(1+a) = 0 $ ?

Comment: $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}nx^n$ so $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}nx^{n-1}$ now expands the series and take the limit $x\rightarrow 0$. Note that the first series term will be 1 and the others 0

Comment: Is there a simpler explanation?

Comment: $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}nx^{n-1}=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{x^4}{5}+...$

Comment: It is Taylor series?

Comment: Yes,it is. See more here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html

Comment: Your solution is correct, but I can't use it. I upvote this, thank you and sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't just evaluate the function at $0$, because it's not even defined there. Anyway you can get:

$$\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+a)}{a} = \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+a) - \ln(1)}{(a+1) - 1} = (\ln(1+x))'|_{x=0} = 1$$

Comment: This a derivative?

Comment: @divisor Yeah it's the definition for derivative

Comment: Unavailable for me...